# php - reading from the end of an array till a specific value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of x ( NOT FIXED ) values. But I need another array that only has the last n values (NOT FIXED) . How do I achieve this?  With this new array of n values, I need two arrays of length n/2 and n/2 that have alternative values of that original n valued array .

I have a specific problem and I have generalized it here . Also, I need to be able to dynamically provide the value "n" inside the code based on some other criterion ...

All using PHP.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you still be clear with ur question, it will help. if you can show the examples of array how it should look, it would be great.

Comment: `array_reverse`, iterate over list, find big number, cut out, reverse result again.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use array_slice where the start is the array length - n

```
$array = array();
$n = 5;
$newArray = array_slice($array, (count($array) - $n) -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to achieve this, so in the example the 2, could be replaced by a fixed `N` try the example with your own array.

> array array_slice ( array $array , int
>   $offset [, int $length [, bool
>   $preserve_keys = false ]] )

```
<?php
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
?>
```